# Is an if-else tree the best way to go in the following case?

Tags: java, optimization, if-statement

**What I'm doing:**

I'm creating a simple calculator in Java, that reads a string that has been written using [postfix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (for example: 3 4 +). It then takes the string and starts reading it from left to right. It stores each number it finds and then applies the following operator. For example: 3 4 + --> store 3, store 4, run 3 + 4 and store result.

**What I need help with:**

In what way characters should be checked against pre-defined operators (if(c == '/') etc). What alternatives are there in my case to an if-else tree, and which one should I choose if I want to be able to add new operators with minimum effort (and minimum toll on performance). What is generally considered good practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you encapsulate your operations as objects, you can often use a data structure to replace a `switch`-like statement and hopefully will simply adding operations in the future.

For example, this is one approach for encapsulating operations as objects: using an Enum to represent the operations:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

```
public enum Operation {
  PLUS   { double eval(double x, double y) { return x + y; } },
  MINUS  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x - y; } },
  TIMES  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x * y; } },
  DIVIDE { double eval(double x, double y) { return x / y; } };

  // Do arithmetic op represented by this constant
  abstract double eval(double x, double y);
}
```

You could extend this example to associate a symbol with each operation and provide a static method to look up the operation associated with symbol. [[ I'm torn about this mixing UI/view code with the logic/domain code, but you mentioned you want simple, so perhaps this is okay for your program.]]

If you encapsulate your operations as objects, then you can consider a data structure to replace switch-like code:

- if there will be a lot of operations, consider building a hashmap to map symbols to operations.
- if there are a small number of operations, it may be cheap enough to have a collection of all operations and simply iterate through all operations to ask each if they act on the user-provided symbol and use the first found.

Comment: remember seeing this in @effectivejava :)

Answer (score 8):

If this is a calculator for humans to use, stop thinking about performance (as in execution speed). No human will ever come close to noticing the difference between an if-tree and any other implementation.

That said, you might want to try implementing some kind of Operator class, that knows how to apply itself to arguments, and then use a hash from the operator name (strings like "+", "-", "*" and so on) to an appropriate instance.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the performance issue. Readability is much more important in almost all situations. (And when your application happens to be so performance-sensitive, arguably you shouldn't be using Java in the first place.)

Comment: @biziclop, on that point, clear, simpler code tends to be faster anyway. Obscure code, tends to confuse not only the JIT but developers trying to maintain it and are are less likely to make efficient changes to the code and can result in the code getting slower over time. (with each change)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey True, attempts to micro-optimise code in a JVM are at best like running on a bus, but you can also make it even worse than it was.

Comment: @biziclop, finding a situation where it will make a real difference requires a very specific business need and can take serious effort.  Usually you need to try many different approaches and test everything very carefully.  It surprisingly rarely worth it.

Comment: @Willi Probably because it is, at least on the level where the performance of character comparisons and branching is a serious factor.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't worry about performance as the computer can parse/calculate the data 1 million times faster than you can type the formula (and that is not an exaguration)

The way I would approach it is to use if/else or use a switch statement

```
switch(ch) {
  case '+':

     break;
  case '-':

     break;
  // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) implemented by a map with `Character` objects as key and instances implementing a handling interface as values.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it by creating an Operator superclass, which is extended by single operations, follows an example (forgive me for errors, I'm not trying this).

```
abstract class Operator {
    String simbol;
    abstract Double calculate(Double firstOperand, Double secondOperand)
}

class Sum extends Operator {
    simbol = "+";
    Double calculate(Double firstOperand, Double secondOperand){
        return firstOperand + secondOperand;
    }    
}

class OperatorRecognizer {
    List<Operator> operators;
    public Operator recognize(String readOperator){
        for(Operator operator : operators){
            if(operator.getSymbol().equals(readOperator)){
                return operator;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While reading a line I would do it this way:

```
OperatorFactory.recognize(readOperator).calculate(firstOperand, secondOperand);
```

This way when you have to add a single operation you just add one class.

EDIT: lol ok, it seems others have said this same thing, I'll leave this here anyway ^^"

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Like many people here, micro optimization causes more evil than good. But without throwing any design patten at you or idea for optimization, this is what  I would do.

I will create am Enum for all operations. I will also create a member function in this enum that takes a var args parameter and a operation enum and iteratively apply the enum operation on the arguements.

I will also create an String utility class (for input processing), that Iterates thro all the operation enum values and performs a regular expression check on input string to identify the operation specified by a given string ( regex because I want to make sure of Postfix notation).  Once it identifies the operation, then it delegates to the enum's member function to perform the operation.